# How to disable logs in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to get rid of the logs that webpack creates , using the 5.73.0 version of webpack.
My webpack configuration , about what's [here](https://github.com/MkinG2k0/capacitor-project-template/tree/master/webpack)

webpack.common.js

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({})]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './public/index.html')
    })
  ],
  stats: 'errors-only'
}
```

webpack.dev.js

```js
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,

    open: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env'
    })
  ]
}
```

Directly these same logs
[image: Directly these same logs]

and something incomprehensible is also happening in the network tab
[image: and something incomprehensible is also happening in the network tab]

Comment: I believe the logs in your console should only happen in development mode and not in production. Do you also want to remove from development mode?

Comment: @FavourFelixChinemerem
Yes , I would like to remove them from development mode too , as it interferes with development .